# Элемент с position:fixed в блоке с position:absolute & overflow-y: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Сразу к коду**

https://jsfiddle.net/afguzLxn/2/

Правый блок контейнер содержит дочерний блок `.child.scrollable`

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Цепляю туда блок для прокрутки по якорям.

```
.pages {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}

.pages ul li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f8b10a;
    color: #000;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Он позиционирован справа, но налазит на полосу скрола. Как это можно пофиксить? Ему конечно можно задать позиционирование относительно края полосы скрола, но ширина в разных браузерах разная.

Comment: Имхо, вы перемудрили. Оставляйте скролл на странице обычный (а не у блока) и думайте как дизайн вписать в эту ситуацию.

Comment: В чем перемудрил то? Sidebar должен быть статическим. Основной контейнер должен скроллится. Другого выхода как реализованный я не знаю например

Comment: слайдеру fixed задать, например?

Comment: По сути это не слайдер, а просто переход по якорям. Если задать .scrollable position:fixed, полоса прокрутки пропадет вообще. Хотя да, прокрутка будет работать

Comment: я имею ввиду - child должен иметь `position:relative`, чтобы скролл на странице образовывался нативным путем. а не костылем типа `.scrollable`. а уж то как прикрепить левый красный блок при скролле - миллион способов, в том числе 'position:fixed' ему

Comment: Сайт сверстан используя display:flex. Тут display:fixed не работает

Comment: я и говорю - перемудрили

Comment: Так в чем же я перемудрил? В том что использовал для верстки технологию упрощающую работу?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29533/discussion-between-wkornilow-and-xaja).